# Checking the intersection multiplicity for two curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hi guys I am using Fulton's book on algebraic curves as a main material to study. I am trying to check the intersection multiplicity of $p=(0,0)$ of $g(x,y)=y^2-x^3-x^2$ and $h(x,y)= y^2-x^3+x$

My approach is inspired by chapter 3.3 of Fulton. 
First $Mult_p(g)=2$ because the we are looking at the origin and thus the multiplicity is the power of the smallest order term of the polynomial. Similarly $Mult_p(h)=1$.

Now I make the following sequence:
$\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I^2 \times \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(g,h,I^3)$.
Where $I=\langle x,y \rangle$

Where we can call the first arrow $\psi(A,B)=Ag+Bh$ and the second to be the projection map $\pi$. Now we notice that the $\ker \pi = \dim \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I^2 + \dim \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ iff and only if $\psi$ is injective.

So that is what we aim to show. Notice that by [Fulton's](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) algebraic curves $I_p(p; F \cap G)= I_p(p; F \cap G+ AF$ and $I_p(p; F \cap G)=I_p(p; G \cap F)$. Thus we can simplify both g and h and doing so I got $g'= g-h=x^2+x$ and $h'= h+xg'-g'=y^2$

Thus we want to show $\ker p= \{Ag' +Bh'\}= I^3$.

My question is this correct so far, am I on the right track. Also is there a overall better way to find the intersection multiplicity.

Comment: Maybe you want to re-read the question and improve it: I don't think a kernel equals a sum of two dimensions. Moreover, when talk about $I_p$ what do you mean by $AF$?

Comment: A is a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. It is a typical approach to simplify in Fulton.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways of computing the intersection number using Fulton's approach.  Fulton lists 7 axioms that the intersection number satisfies on pp. 36-37.

The quick way: Axiom (5) states that $I_P(g \cap h) \geq m_P(g) m_P(h)$ with equality if $g$ and $h$ have no common tangents at $P$.  Examining the homogeneous terms of lowest order, we find
$$
y^2 - x^2 = (y-x)(y+x) \implies g \text{ has tangents } y-x, y+x\\
$$
and $h$ has the single tangent $x$ at $P$.  Using the multiplicities you've already computed, we find $I_P(g \cap h) = 2 \cdot 1 = 2$.

Another way: We can use axiom (7), as you suggested.  Note that
$$h - g = y^2 - x^3 + x - (y^2 - x^3 - x^2) = x^2 + x \, .$$
Using axioms (7) and (6), we find
\begin{align*}
I_P(g \cap h) &= I_P(y^2 - x^3 - x^2 \cap y^2 - x^3 + x) \overset{(7)}{=} I_P(y^2 - x^3 - x^2 \cap x^2 + x)\\
&\overset{(7)}{=} I_P(y^2 \cap x(x+1)) \overset{(6)}{=} I_P(y^2 \cap x) + I_P(y^2 \cap x + 1) \overset{(2)}{=} I_P(y^2 \cap x) = 2 \, .
\end{align*}
(Since $P$ doesn't lie on the intersection of $y^2$ and $x+1$, which consists only of the point $(-1,0)$, then $I_P(y^2 \cap x+1) = 0$ by axiom (2).)

Comment: If I had to find the multiplicity of the intersection of the $g(x,y)=xy^2+x^4$ and $h(x,y)=x^2y-x^4$ curves, then these curves do not have tangents in common and so I can use $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)$ to get to that $I_p(g\cap h)=m_p(h)\cdot m_p(g)=3\cdot 3=9$?

Comment: Those curves have tangents in common at (0,0) (which I assume is the point you are considering), namely  and , as can be seen from factoring their lowest degree terms. In fact, those curves have a common component $x = 0$, so I don't think their intersection multiplicity is defined. In any case, I suggest you ask a new question.