# Calculate the multiplicity at the origin of the intersection of the curves $X=V(xy^2+x^4)$ and $Y=V(x^2y-x^4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

**Calculate the multiplicity at the origin of the intersection of the curves $X=V(xy^2+x^4)$ and $Y=V(x^2y-x^4)$.**

I have tried to do the following:

$\mu_0(xy^2+x^4, x^2y-x^4)\\
=\mu_0(x(y^2+x^3), x^2y-x^4)\\
=\mu_0(x, x^2y-x^4)+\mu_0(y^2+x^3, x^2y-x^4)\\
=\mu_0(x, x^2y)+\mu_0(y^2+x^3, x^2(y-x^2))\\
=\mu_0(x, x^2)+\mu_0(x, y)+\mu_0(y^2+x^3, x^2)+\mu_0(y^2+x^3, y-x^2)\\
=\mu_0(x, x^2)+1+\mu_0(x^2, y^2)+\mu_0(y^2+x^3, y-x^2)\\
=5+\mu_0(x, x^2)+\mu_0(y^2+x^3, y-x^2)$

I don't know how to calculate $\mu_0(x, x^2)$ and $\mu_0(y^2+x^3, y-x^2)$, could someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: As I mentioned to you in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696061/checking-the-intersection-multiplicity-for-two-curves/1696559#comment6819573_1696559), these two curves have a component in common, namely $x = 0$. Thus the intersection number at the origin is $\infty$. (See p. 38 of Fulton's curve book.)