# Multiplicity at the origin of the intersection of the curves $X=V(xy^2+x^4)$ and $Y=V(x^2y-x^4)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, intersection-theory

**Calculate the multiplicity at the origin of the intersection of the curves $X=V(xy^2+x^4)$ and $Y=V(x^2y-x^4)$.**

This question was already posted here [Calculate the multiplicity at the origin of the intersection of the curves $X=V(xy^2+x^4)$ and $Y=V(x^2y-x^4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315595), but I would like to know how to solve this using that $I_P(X\cap Y)=\dim_k(\mathbb{O}_p(A^2)/(f,g))$? In this case what would $\mathbb{O}_p(A^2)$ and $(f,g)$ be? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\Bbb{O}_p(A^2)$ is kind of funny - it's more usually rendered as $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^2_k,p}$. This is the local ring of $\Bbb A^2_k$ at the point $p$ - in this case, it's $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}$. $(f,g)$ is the ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^2_k,p}$ generated by $f$ and $g$: in this case, $f=xy^2+x^4$ and $g=x^2y-x^4$. From here you're just computing the dimension of the quotient as a $k$-algebra, which should be straightforwards.

Comment: I know that it is $f$ and $g$, which is not what ideal is isomorphic $(f,g)$ to be able to calculate the quotient $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(f,g)$ and then its dimension.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment - are you saying that you're having trouble doing the calculation? If that's the case, look at $y$ - is it in the ideal you're quotienting by? Are it's powers?

Comment: Yes, I am having trouble calculating this: could I conclude that $(f,g)=(xy^2+x^4,x^2y-x^4)=(x,y)$?

Comment: That's not true, and you should know this from the answer to the linked question - if that were true, the dimension of $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb A^2_k,p}/I$ would be one, which doesn't match the solution provided. Try again with the hint from the previous comment.